# jhipster Not working the POST REST API

Tags: java, post, jhipster

I want to POST value to an entity in JHIPSTER

I have in my entity name Hussain with one field called name with a type Long

I write this code but it gives me an error 401 if only post a name 
and if I add id with it I got 400 error

```
        private void sendPost(long n) throws Exception {
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/api/hussains";

            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            //add request header
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1dGgiOiJST0xFX0FETUlOLFJPTEVfVVNFUiIsImV4cCI6MTUzNDA4Nzg4OX0.AbI_AmN8ePTZ2blULuAKlls-YUPYMD9EHBqIgk_fbktdzJH7hhkEYhQw7settlM04n5N2MHRtGzC1b4z_PDw-Q");

            // optional default is POST
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");

             //Create JSONObject here
            JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
            jsonParam.put("name", 10);
            OutputStreamWriter out = new   OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
            out.write(jsonParam.toString());
            out.close();  



            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            //print result
            System.out.println(response.toString());

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);


        }
```

and i got this error

```
    java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8080/api/hussains
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1840)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
```

Comment: It seems you are sending  a "hussain" with an id  (`id: "11"`). It seems this is not possible. Have you tried it without id?

Comment: @vstm yes but is not working

Comment: I am following  the example in  jhipster  API POST method but it is not work

Comment: In JHipster a POST requires that there is no ID, check HussainResource.java . Please edit your question with details to show what is not working when you POST with only a neme and no id.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou ok I will edit my question

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't have to send id with POST method because id will be created by your back-end.

You get 401 which is unauthorized so you have to find out whether your request is authenticated and unauthorized or not.

You get 400 because of Bad Request.

Comment: Ok thanx, I solve my problem but now I have author how I can get Token Bearer Dynamic from JHipster ?

Comment: for that you can raise another exclusive question...accept and upvote if my answer helped you..thanks